# Parsing json data with random keys(keys not staying the same throughout)

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

How can i parse below json data with inconsistent keys inside data object?The key names 2016 and 2015 are not fixed and are random .There can be more arrays inside data object with random key names.Can i create a model class with such json data?Can i use gson with this?

Comment: You can refer to this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31025810/3940292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make model with unknown keys. If you wanna make model then you have to know keys name.
Yes, you can read dynamic json like this

```
JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");// here response is server response
Iterator keys = data.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    // loop to get the dynamic key
    String key = (String)keys.next();

    // get the value of the dynamic key
    JSONArray value = data.getJSONArray(key);

    // do your more stuff here
}
```

Comment: questionMark? It shoule be data.getJSONArray(currentDynamicKey);

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
    JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    int responseCode=jsonO.getInt("responseCode");
    String responseMessage=jsonO.getString("responseMessage");

    JSONObject jsondata=jsonO.getJSONObject("data");

    for (String key : jsondata.keys()) {
        Object o = jsondata.get(key)
        if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsonA = (JSONArray) o;
            int muberOfItems = jsonA.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < muberOfItems; i++) {
                //parse your Data
            }
        } else { //must be some other value }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this with `GSON`. This worked for me,

**POJO classes**

ParsedData.java

```
public class ParsedData {

    private Integer responseCode;
    private String responseMessage;
    Map<String, List<List<Item>>> data = new HashMap<String, List<List<Item>>>();

    public Integer getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(Integer responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public String getResponseMessage() {
        return responseMessage;
    }

    public void setResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {
        this.responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public Map<String, List<List<Item>>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, List<List<Item>>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**GSON code**

```
String data = "{\n" +
        "\t\"responseCode\": 200,\n" +
        "\t\"responseMessage\": \"Operation succeeded successfully\",\n" +
        "\t\"data\": {\n" +
        "\t\t\"2016\": [\n" +
        "\t\t\t[{\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Id\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"101_202704916\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"amount\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"1.48\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Type\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"gchgch\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}],\n" +
        "\t\t\t[{\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Id\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"101_202704916\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"amount\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"1.48\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Type\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"gchgch\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t}]\n" +
        "\t\t],\n" +
        "\t\t\"2015\": [\n" +
        "\t\t\t[{\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Id\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"101_202704916\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"amount\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"1.48\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Type\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"gchgch\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\t\t\t],\n" +
        "\t\t\t[{\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Id\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"101_202704916\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"amount\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"1.48\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}, {\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"key\": \"Type\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"gchgch\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t\t}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\t\t\t]\n" +
        "\t\t]\n" +
        "\t}\n" +
        "}";

ParsedData data1 = new Gson().fromJson(data, ParsedData.class);
for (String key : data1.getData().keySet()) {
    List<List<Item>> items = data1.getData().get(key);
    for (List<Item> item : items) {
        for (Item item1 : item) {
            Log.e("TAG", item1.getKey() + " : " + item1.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this Simple :

```
    String response = "YOUR RESPONSE";

    JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject jsonObject = resObj.getJSONObject("data");
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap2015 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap2016 = new HashMap<>();

    if (jsonObject.has("2015")) {
        JSONArray jsonArray2015 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("2015");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2015.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray2015.getJSONObject(i);
            hashMap2015.put(jsonObject1.getString("key"), jsonObject1.getString("value"));
        }
    }

    if (jsonObject.has("2016")) {
        JSONArray jsonArray2016 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("2016");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2016.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray2016.getJSONObject(i);
            hashMap2016.put(jsonObject1.getString("key"), jsonObject1.getString("value"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The key names 2016 and 2015 are not fixed and are random .There can be more arrays inside data object with random key names and number of arrays inside data object is not fixed.

Comment: @Bhuvi you can follow the answer of Dharmbir Singh and Sagar Zala , above answer are also working

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
 try{
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(object.getJSONObject("data"));
    JSONArray arr2015 = new JSONArray(data);
    for(int ePos = 0; ePos < arr2015.lenght; ePos ++){
           JSONObject insideArr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(ePos);
           String key = insideAr.getString("key")
           String value = insideAr.getString("value")
           //add this values to your object

    }
    JSONArray arr2016 = new JSONArray(data);
    for(int ePos = 0; ePos < arr2016.lenght; ePos ++){
           JSONObject insideArr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(ePos);
           String key = insideAr.getString("key")
           String value = insideAr.getString("value")
            //add this values to your object
    }

}catch (JSONException e){
    return e.getMessage();
}
```